# Can I change attorney ad litem?

Tags: family-law, arkansas

I’m in a custody battle in Arkansas. We still have 10 months until the final date of court. Our attorney ad litem appointed for our 2 year old daughter is extremely biased against me. I can feel it and don’t trust her. Can I request the court to change AAL?

Comment: who appointed the attorney in the first place? Everything else: ask **YOUR** lawyer. They ought to know.

Comment: Court appointed. Do I have a right to request to change her?

Comment: Ask your attorney. AFAIK, you are required to have an attorney in family court anyway.

Comment: Before rocking the boat and asking attorney, I want to know is this possible? Is this a normal thing to ask?

Comment: Your attorney is not going to tell the court or the other party. He is however the best person to know if there is anything to be done and if he can file a motion with any chance of success.

Comment: Attorney ad litem is regulated in [Arkansas Code Title 9. Family Law § 9-13-101 (e)](https://codes.findlaw.com/ar/title-9-family-law/ar-code-sect-9-13-101.html), most of which regulates who pays for the attorney or what qualifications they need.

Comment: If you want to know if it's possible or normal, *ask your lawyer*. A bunch of yoohoos on the Internet cannot give you superior information.

Comment: I agree with @Trish but I want to point out that _the attorney ad litem is not your lawyer._ The question suggests that you might not understand this (you mention "our" attorney ad litem). The job of the attorney ad litem is to represent _your daughter's_ interests, which might not align with yours. This is why you need your own lawyer. The attorney ad litem might be skeptical of you and your submissions to the court; that's her job.  It doesn't necessarily mean that she is biased against you.  If her skepticism is well founded, an attempt to have her replaced may work against you.

Comment: @Trish "you are required to have an attorney in family court anyway" almost certainly not true. A majority of family court litigants are *pro se*.

Answer (score 6):

This person is appointed by the court to look after the child's interests recognizing that the child's interests may be different from those of the parents. As @phoog notes in the comments:

> the attorney ad litem is not your lawyer. The question suggests that
> you might not understand this (you mention "our" attorney ad litem).
> The job of the attorney ad litem is to represent your daughter's
> interests, which might not align with yours. This is why you need your
> own lawyer. The attorney ad litem might be skeptical of you and your
> submissions to the court; that's her job. It doesn't necessarily mean
> that she is biased against you. If her skepticism is well founded, an
> attempt to have her replaced may work against you.

(FYI, most jurisdictions call this person a "guardian ad litem" or GAL, but Arkansas uses atypical terminology.)

> Our attorney ad litem appointed for our 2 year old daughter is
> extremely biased against me.

This is not a reason to remove the person appointed. It is their job to distrust parents and provide an independent opinion to the court.

There could be grounds for removing a guardian ad litem (e.g. a personal relationship with one of the parties prior to the litigation), but nothing in this question suggests that any relevant facts are present.

You would be much better served trying to figure out what causes the guardian ad litem to distrust you and to find a way to show that person that their distrust of you is ill-founded.

Answer (score 6):

The attorney ad litem **is on the opposing side**.

There are 3 teams on the field: you, your ex and your child.

They don't wear team jerseys in legal work, but if they did, the *attorney ad litem* would be wearing a different color jersey than you.

That is why they seem extremely biased against you.

You should not even be talking to them. That's why you have a lawyer.

If you don't have a lawyer, and have been clinging to the *attorney ad litem* to try to get free legal advice, that would partly explain their hostility.  They can't give you legal advice.  If you think they have, no, they have been negotiating with an opponent.